# paper-radio-group buttons inside a template possible?

Tags: html, data-binding, polymer, web-component

I'm creating a project with Polymer and have the following code:

```
<paper-radio-group>
    <template repeat="{{answer in answers}}">
        <p>
            <paper-radio-button name="{{answer.choice}}" label="{{answer.choice}}"></paper-radio-button>
        </p>
    </template>
</paper-radio-group>
```

I have a list of answers that I want to use in the paper-radio-group. Displaying this works fine. Every item in the answers array is displayed as a paper-radio-button.

The problem is that they are not connected to each other. So, when selecting one paper-radio-button, another is not deselected. This is probably because the paper-radio-group tag is outside the template tag. But placing it inside would make it repeat like the paper-radio-button and that's not going to work either.

Is there a way to get this to work? Or is it not possible?

Comment: Have you tried without `<p>`

Comment: That seems to work Günter! Thanks. If you place the answer below, I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<paper-radio-group>` expects `<paper-radio-button>` as it's children. When you wrap them in other elements like `<p>` the `<paper-radio-group>` can't manage the state.
The `<template>` element is is not actually included in the DOM and doesn't get in the way when the elements are rendered.

Comment: Do you also know what is the proper solution if we need to use it in a tag (e.g "<p>")

Comment: Sorry, don't know.